# How to use index in mapOf

Tags: kotlin, dictionary

In python I can use

```
X = {A: "Apple", B: "Banana"}
print(x.value[0]) //Apple
```

In kotlin can i use ?

```
println(x.value[0]) // Apple
```

Comment: What version of Python do you mean? I believe this code is not a valid Python code. Maps/dictionaries are generally unordered and usually we shouldn't even try to access their '0' item as this is meaningless for maps. Maps can optionally keep ordering (and as a matter of fact, the default implementation in Kotlin does this), but they still don't provide a convenient API to access items by an index.

Answer (score 1):

`Map`s in Kotlin aren't meant to be accessed by index, so you can't do that directly. They do store entries in the order they're added (with the default `Map` types) which means you *can* convert them into an `Iterable` and get the first item, or whatever

```
val fruits = mapOf("A" to "Apple", "B" to "Banana")
// access values directly, use first() for readability
println(fruits.values.first())
// access elements, use an index, pull the value out of the entry
println(fruits.entries.elementAt(1).value)
// etc
```

Those properties just create an ordered `Set` of the *entries*, *values* etc, so you're just creating another container with a view of the existing objects.